# How to count number of times that a mathcing string appears in a cell in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column in Excel where there are some strings separated by commas. For example:

> Seg, Ter, Qua, Seg
>
> Qui, Sex
>
> Sab, Sab
>
> Seg
>
> Dom, Seg

(There are rows that can be null)

I want to count the number of different strings in each row, in the exemple above i would like the output to be:

> Seg: 2, Ter: 1, Qua: 1
>
> Qui: 1, Sex: 1
>
> Sab: 2
>
> Seg: 1
>
> Dom: 1, Seg: 1

Is there a way for me to do this in Excel?

Comment: `Is there a way for me to do this in Excel` - Yes, you can use VBa

Comment: To expand on @Dave's comment, you'll want to use the SPLIT function (https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php) to split your values into an array of substrings, then count the occurrences of the value you're looking for in the substrings.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following **User Defined Function**:

```
Public Function Components(sIN As String) As String
    Dim c As Collection, bry(), L As Long

    L = Len(sIN)
    Set c = New Collection
    ary = Split(sIN, ", ")
    On Error Resume Next
        For Each a In ary
            c.Add a, CStr(a)
        Next a
    On Error GoTo 0

    ReDim bry(1 To c.Count)
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        bry(i) = c.Item(i)
        Kount = (L - Len(Replace(sIN, bry(i), ""))) / Len(bry(i))
        Components = Components & bry(i) & ":" & Kount & ", "
    Next i

    Components = Left(Components, Len(Components) - 2)
End Function
```

[image]